# Is third root of x is contraction mapping?

Tags: contraction-operator

I need some help with proving that $$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}+2$$ is a contraction mapping $(f: \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{R})$.
So I need to show that there exist $\alpha\in (0,1)$ such that for all $x,y$ 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \alpha|x-y|.$$

I have nothing so I need any help. Thank you!

Comment: It isn't a contraction.  Consider what happens when $y=0$ and $x$ is close to $0$.

Comment: ooooh okay, sure! thank you very much!